# Window.load doesn't working

Tags: javascript, html

Can some one please tell me why the next code isn't working?

```
var nump = 0;
 function point() {
  nump++;
  document.getElementById('point').style.margin = nump + 'px 0px 0px';
 }
window.onload = point();
```

I trying make div move when window is loaded, thank you all.

Comment: try document.onload instead of window. ...

Comment: Its not it.. still not working.

Comment: do you see any errors in console ?

Comment: remove the (). `window.onload = point;`

Comment: Not really, the error list is clear.

Comment: The out post is div point will move down with the margin

Comment: The removing () not helping me.

Comment: Remove var before nump, and, however, this will move div 1px.

Comment: which margin do you want to change? you have 3 values: nump and 0px + 0px

Comment: nump = 0.. so the margin is 0px 0px 0px then nump count 1 each time so it 1px, 2px and so on..

Comment: @Sergio It's still not it..

Comment: No, this will not work - on body load, nump is increased for 1 - so, no visible change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning an event handler that is a named function is done without the ()

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/26Gmt/) based on your fiddle

```
var nump = 100; // setting a value that actually is visible
function point() {
  nump++;
  document.getElementById('point').style.margin = nump + 'px 0px 0px';
}
window.onload = point;
```

unless the named function returns a function.

Since you are using jQuery:

```
var nump = 0;
function point() {
  nump++;
  document.getElementById('point').style.margin = nump + 'px 0px 0px';
}
$(function() {
  point(); // will move 1 pixel
});
```

Perhaps you mean

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    point(); // will move 1 pixel
  },100); // move one pixel every 100ms
});
```

Comment: It's not working really, it still not moving. The whole page - http://jsfiddle.net/myC7J/

Comment: Of course it is working. Change 0 to 100 and you will see the ball drop

Comment: I guess you didn't really understood me, it not moving like the player div, try press left or right arrow and see what i mean, i want the same on the ball just the ball will work automatically..

Comment: Then you need to tell that in the question. Your code was wrong in both syntax and logic then

Comment: I'm sorry, it was kinda hard to explain.. But it still not working, please give me something useful.

Comment: YW. Btw there is no onload of a div so `$('.point').load(function random() {` does not make any sense

Comment: @yotam setInterval is not encouraged to use, it may have timing issues. Perhaps take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17144415/1047823).

Comment: @Christoph Thanks but the time isn't the point, all i need is just make it move, doesn't matter what time, thanks anyway.

Comment: @yotam I just wanted to say that setInterval is probably not a good solution later on.

Answer (score 0):

To extend [@mplungjan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17144307/887539): You should only assign the necessary style with JavaScript no need to change anything else then the margin-top property:

```
var nump = 0;
window.onload=function() {
  nump++;
  document.getElementById('point').style.marginTop = nump;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to hand over a function reference:

```
window.onload = point;
```

2) Your comment

> I trying make div move when window is loaded

makes me assume, you want to call the function recursively which should be done in the following way:

```
function point() {
    nump+=4;
    document.getElementById('point').style.margin = nump + 'px 0px 0px';
    // exemplary constraint to exit the loop, change to your liking
    if (nump < 300){setTimeout(point,20);}
}
```

[your modified Example](http://jsfiddle.net/myC7J/3/)

Comment: Why would that give any different result than setInterval?

Comment: @mplungjan Difficult to explain in the comment section alone, better read [John's article](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) about timers in javascript. `"setTimeout and setInterval are fundamentally different in how they execute asynchronous code."` Basically setInterval can have dropouts.

Answer (score 0):

By moving, do you want to say, like this : http://jsfiddle.net/myC7J/1/

Which would be adding a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) like this :

```
var interval;
window.onload = function(){ interval = setInterval(point, 100);}
```

**EDIT :**

Since it seems you want to make a game :
If you want to play with position in DOM, why don't you use `position: absolute` , `top` and `left`
Else, you should consider using Canvas.

Comment: @mplungjan both works, still it would be better to add the `setInterval` to a variable so you could use `clearInterval` like this : `var interval; window.onload= function(){ interval = setInterval(point, 100);` Thanks for copying my answer anyway ;-)

Comment: Yes I've meant that but i got answer, that you still.